# Conditional Background Image in RDLC Report

Tags: rdlc, dynamics-365

I am trying to show a watermark as a "background image" in an RDLC report, dependent on dataset values.

I set up conditional background images in the report based on the first instance of "field1, 2, 3" in the dataset. (see expression)

```
=IIf(Fields!Field1.Value = "True", "Image1", IIf(Fields!Field2.Value = "True", "Image2", IIF(Fields!Field3.Value = "XYZ Item","Image3","")))
```

This works fine for reports with a single document. But when dealing with multiple documents in a single report, the background image is determined only by the first item in the dataset. So the background image is the same across all pages, not changing with the dataset's grouping and repetition.
How can I make the background image conditional for each page/document individually in the report?
I'm Using RDLC Report Designer for Visual Studio.